# React native flatlist show from bottom using inverted ={true}, but i want if item not able to fill full screen its show from top

Tags: flatlist

```
                    <FlatList
                        data={data}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1}}
                        ref={flatListRef}
                        inverted={true}
                    />
```

When i try this in all item show from bottom, and scroll bottom to top.I want this behaviour. But if data item size only one or two i want to show item from screen top.

Answer (score 1):

I find this answer for this issue change replace
this line

```
contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1}}
```

with this line

```
contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}
```